# Add onClick="myFunction()" on radio button in SuiteCRM Custom Module

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I've tried to add onClick="myFunction()" on radio button in SuiteCRM Custom Module but no success.

I followed different post online but nothing to do.

I suppose that I have to add some string in my field array but I don't know how.

My Array is:

```
'valore_dispositivo' => 
array (
  'required' => true,
  'name' => 'valore_dispositivo',
  'vname' => 'LBL_VALORE_DISPOSITIVO',
  'type' => 'radioenum',
  'massupdate' => '1',
  'no_default' => false,
  'importable' => 'true',
  'duplicate_merge' => 'disabled',
  'duplicate_merge_dom_value' => '0',
  'audited' => true,
  'inline_edit' => true,
  'reportable' => true,
  'unified_search' => false,
  'merge_filter' => 'disabled',
  'len' => 100,
  'size' => '20',
  'options' => 'fasce_list',
  'studio' => 'visible',
  'dbType' => 'enum',
  'separator' => '<br>',
),
```

I also try to add 'displayParams' (or something like that) but still no success.